# Is is possible to implement internal shell command (shell builtin) by only using the exec() functions?

Tags: c, linux

I want to implement some Linux commands by only using the `exec()` family of functions. When I use external commands such as "ls", "whoami", it runs well. However, I can't run internal commands (shell builtins) such as "export". Is there any other way to run those commands? And also, why can `system()` implement those internal commands even though it uses `execl()` function?

Comment: You can't sensibly implement built-in functions like `cd` (though there is `/usr/bin/cd` on macOS, for example, but it doesn't change the directory of the shell that invokes it).  The `system()` function can do `export`, but it doesn't affect the environment of the program that calls `system()` — it only affects the shell that `system()` runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Linux implementation of `system` does indeed use `execl`, but it uses it to run a shell, not to directly invoke the utility. `man system` is quite explicit:

> The  `system()`  library  function uses `fork(2)` to create a child process that executes the shell command specified in command using `execl(3)` as follows:
>
> ```
>    execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char *) 0);
> ```

So `system` runs an instance of the standard shell (`/bin/sh`), passing it two command-line parameters: `-c` and the argument to `system`. Shells are expected to interpret the command-line flag `-c` as requesting the the shell execute the following argument as a shell command. The shell will certainly be able to execute its own builtins from a `-c` argument in the same way that it executes them if you type them interactively.

However, although you can execute a `cd` or `export` command with `system`, you will find that it is utterly pointless because it works on the execution environment of the shell invoked by `system`. That shell will terminate as soon as it finishes executing the command it has been asked to execute, so any changes to its execution environment will immediately vanish.

So that's not very useful if you are trying to write a shell. You will want `cd` to actually change working directories and `export` to modify your shell's environment variables. So, just like the system shell, you'll have to implement your own builtins. As the word "builtin" implies, these commands are interpreted directly by the shell itself, rather than being passed to some external utility to implement.

For these particular commands, you'll probably want to investigate the standard library functions `setenv(3)` (to modify environment variables) and `chdir(2)` (to change the current working directory).